# Find out the "max" of a column and the value of another column for the corresponding row

Tags: r

In a huge dataframe, I want to find out the max value of multiple columns.

With those values, I want to find and print the values of a different column for the rows where the first column contains these "max" values.

For example, using the [`mtcars` built-in dataframe](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame), I want to find the max value for the columns `qsec`, `hp` and `wt`. Then, using those max column values, locate and print the value from the `mpg` column for the rows that contain those max `qsec`, `hp` and `wt` values.

Comment: `mtcars$mpg[which.max(mtcars$qsec)]`

Comment: Try `mtcars %>% slice(which.max(qsec))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use dplyr to achieve this.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars_maxvals <- mtcars %>%
       select(mpg, qsec, hp, wt) %>%
       gather(col, val, -mpg) %>%
       group_by(col) %>%
       filter(val==max(val)) %>%
       ungroup()
```

I included the select statement because you specified those three columns, but if you remove it, you'd get the max value and corresponding mpg for all columns. Also, if there were multiple mpg values for the corresponding maximum of another variable, you would also see that.

Comment: Perhaps not a good idea to call this new data frame `mtcars` as well?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a specific desired output. Here's something that seems to do what you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  filter(qsec == max(qsec, na.rm = TRUE) | 
           hp == max(hp, na.rm = TRUE) | 
           wt == max(wt, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(qsec, hp, wt, mpg)
```

You say you have a huge dataframe. Here's a `data.table` version that is about 15x faster on my machine, at least on the very small `mtcars` dataset. I don't know how it scales:

```
mtdt[qsec == max(qsec, na.rm = TRUE) |
   hp == max(hp, na.rm = TRUE) | 
   wt == max(wt, na.rm = TRUE), .(qsec, hp, wt, mpg)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 row.ind <- apply(mtcars[,c(4,6:7)], 2, function(x)order(x,decreasing=T)[1]) 
 mtcars$mpg[row.ind]    OR
 mtcars[row.ind,c(1,4,6:7)] ##for the subsetted dataframe
```

### Faster version using vectorised function which.max()

```
row.ind <- apply(mtcars[,c(4,6:7)], 2, function(x)which.max(x))           
mtcars[row.ind,c(1,4,6:7)]
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `apply` on a data frame, because `apply` first turns the data frame into an array and coerces all entries to the most general type. For example, if there were a column of characters, everything is changed to characters and that messes up any subsequent max finding or sorting. Also, finding the maximum is much less computationally than sorting, which you have done and isn't necessary for the problem.

Comment: Apply does have issues in a dataframe with mixed classes. However, the computation can be limited to columns of numeric class to apply the statistics as in this particular case. Changed the sort to a faster function as per @ngm suggestion..